# How to add symbols or characters between each react element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am designing a reusable component for breadcrumbs and I am using compound components pattern. I need to insert symbols between each breadcrumb name like how we would do for array elements and use join method but I am not sure how to do that with react elements.

```
import React from "react";

const BreadcrumbsItem = ({ children }) => (
  <p>
    {children}
  </p>
);

const Breadcrumbs = ({ children }) => <FlexContainer>{children}</FlexContainer>;

Breadcrumbs.Item = BreadcrumbsItem;

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

Input:

```
<Breadcrumbs>
  <Breadcrumbs.Item>Home</Breadcrumbs.Item>
  <Breadcrumbs.Item>Library</Breadcrumbs.Item>
  <Breadcrumbs.Item>Data</Breadcrumbs.Item>
</Breadcrumbs>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can create a reusable component and add in between the `Breadcrumbs.Item`

Comment: I want to dynamically generate '/' symbol between each breadcrumb name instead of manually entering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions for you:

1. Using CSS
2. Returning fragments
3. Using inserted content

### Using CSS

Assuming this is for the browser and you want the same delimiter (or one of a small set of them), I'd do it with CSS:

```css
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: " / ";
}
```

That says "On a `.breadcrumb-item` that immediately follows another `.breadcrumb-item` (using the [next sibling combinator, `+`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), use `/` as the "before" pseudo-element text (using the [`::before`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-before) pseudo-class and [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)).

Example:

```css
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: " / ";
}
```

```html
<span class="breadcrumb-item">A</span>
<span class="breadcrumb-item">B</span>
<span class="breadcrumb-item">C</span>
```

You could use additional classes to choose among delimiters, or even make the content dependent on an attribute:

Example:

```css
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: attr(data-before);
}
```

```html
<span class="breadcrumb-item">A</span>
<span class="breadcrumb-item" data-before="*">B</span>
<span class="breadcrumb-item" data-before="/">C</span>
```

### Returning fragments

Your `Breadcrumb.Item` element could return a fragment when it needs to have a delimiter in front of it:

```
const content = /*...the rendering of the breadcrumb...*/;
if (delimiter) {
    return <>{delimiter}{content}</>;
}
return content;
```

### Using inserted content

In the `Breadcrumbs` component, you can convert the `children` property to an array via [`React.Children.toArray`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray):

```
const childArray = React.Children.toArray(children);
```

Then you can insert what you like between them, perhaps with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
return <div>{childArray.flatMap((crumb, index) => index === 0 ? crumb : [" / ", crumb])}</div>;
```

You'll need to add keys to those, though (and not using `index` unless you [know the details of why that's usually not a good idea](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). How you add the keys and the values you use for them are highly specific to your code, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to do within code instead of css? Like how we do join method for arrays. Because later at some point I am also add icons instead of symbols.

Comment: @KishoreS - You can control what appears in front with CSS, too. I've shown how to do that, and added a couple of other approaches that actually insert content.